# Monitor GC when a java program run entirely by the interpreter (-Xint option)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, visualvm

I use  VisualVM 1.3.9 and I would like to monitor the garbage collection applied on a java program that I execute with the -Xint option.

This option simply means that I would like to run my program by using only the interpreter.

However the GC plugin in visualvm says that this is  not supported on this VM.

Is it possible to monitor GC when program execution is entirely on the interpreter? If yes how this can be possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'GC plugin'? Did you try to run your application without -Xint option to verify that your 'GC plugin' works fine?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a view of the garbage collection process java provides a program named "visualgc". This tool however does not support garbage collection when one runs programs in interpreting mode (-Xint option).

So my question is there any other tool for monitoring garbage collection at real time? In particular I would like to see how objects are moved from Eden space to S0 and S1 etc.